# Export "mdbDatePicker" was not found in "mdbvue"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, mdbootstrap

I'm using **mdboostrap** for my vuejs project but when I am using **DatePicker** provided by mdb I'm getting an error of ***mdbDatePicker*** not found in ***mdbvue***.

```
<template> 
  <mdb-date-picker v-model="date" />
</template>
```

```
<script>
import {
  mdbDatePicker 
} from "mdbvue";

export default {
  name: "DemoExample",
  components: {
   mdbDatePicker 
  },
  data() {
    return {
      date: ''
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have checked it, but it is a "PRO" component. If you are using the free version, you won't be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Something is seriously wrong with the "mdbVue" package.

I just tried following their documentation [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/education/vue/agenda-app-2-bootstrap/)

And even the first example isn't working properly. It says errors for container,row and column components.

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: mdb-container - did you register
>   the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to
>   provide the "name" option.

I would suggest you try using another library like Vuetify (based on material design as well), Buefy or just simple vue-bootstrap.

Apologies for not being able to help much.

Comment: Yeah looks like that way. Even dropdown in latest version isn't working. Maybe time to opt for another material design.

Answer (score -2):

Following [this guide](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/getting-started/quick-start/) is helpful while having installation problems.